# Understanding a bit of code

Tags: c++, c

I came across this for loop what it is this use for

```
if(__builtin_popcount(mask) % 2 == K % 2) // Do somethings
```

What the `__builtin_popcount` function do ?

Comment: Is google not working? "Returns the number of 1-bits in x.", from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.3/gcc/Other-Builtins.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried googling for it? [Here's](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.3/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) the first hit and the answer:

> — Built-in Function: int __builtin_popcount (unsigned int x)
>
> ```
> Returns the number of 1-bits in x.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It counts the number of set bits in `mask`.  You can check out the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) to answer questions like this one in the future:

> — Built-in Function: `int __builtin_popcount (unsigned int x)`
>
> Returns the number of 1-bits in x.

Answer (score 0):

It returns the number of '1' digits in the binary value.

Answer (score 0):

Returns the number of 1-bits in mask.